# Task Scheduler opens command prompt but does not run python script

Tags: python, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I run a python script from my command prompt once per day, but I want to automate this with task scheduler. I can only make it open Command Prompt, but I have to then run the python program manually. What am I missing?

1. New Folder myTasks
2. Create basic Task
3. Task name, trigger, start a program
4. Program script/ `cmd.exe`
5. Add Arguments: `"C:\Users\Matthew Olive\PycharmProjects\VOLALGO1\scraper.py"`
6. Manually Run Task to test it

All I get is the command prompt opening up and it displays: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

It wont actually run the python script.
If I type `python "C:\Users\Matthew Olive\PycharmProjects\VOLALGO1\scraper.py"`after `C:\WINDOWS\system32>` it will run just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `cmd.exe` you could directly use the `python.exe` with the full path to it. An example location of where it might be is

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CaffeinatedCoder! I figured it out!

I used exactly that for the program/script and it worked. Turns out it was running in the python terminal, but it would disappear immediately, so I added `input("Press Enter to Exit...")`to the end of the python script.

Comment: That's great to hear! If my solution resolved your question please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it :)